# Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array

Tags: php, arrays, boolean, warnings

Hi I have encountered an issue on my website. The following PHP code snippet appears on my front end website displayed behind my layers. I am not a coder but can make changes to the php if necessary. Please can anyone assist?

Warning message:

> Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given
>   /home/gordonfrasier/public_html/wp-content/plugins/divi-overlays/divi-overlays.php
>   on line 2617

The code:
}

```
            if ( $display_in_posts == 'all' ) {

                $display_in_current = true;
**Line 2617 ------------->** $except_in_posts = array_filter( get_post_meta( $overlay_id, 'do_at_pagesexception_selected' ) );

                if ( isset ( $except_in_posts[0] ) ) {

                    foreach( $except_in_posts[0] as $in_post => $the_id ) {

                        if ( $the_id == $current_post_id ) {

                            $display_in_current = false;

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: We need to see the get_post_meta function

Comment: The error is telling you that the first parameter you're giving to array_filter is not an array, when it needs to be. So presumably the `get_post_meta` function does not return an array. Presumably it returns a boolean (i.e. true or false), seeing as that is what the error is telling you as well. But you didn't show us that function (or even its output), so we cannot tell you for sure how to fix it.

Comment: @iJamesPHP2 I'm pretty sure it's a WordPress function.

Comment: @ADyson I'm pretty sure it's a WordPress function, not something he wrote.

Comment: @iJames Hi James apologies yes it is a WordPress function with theme editor Divi

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress `get_post_meta()` function can potentially return a single value.

To work around this you can do this in replacement of your faulty line:

```
$postMeta = get_post_meta( $overlay_id, 'do_at_pagesexception_selected');
$except_in_posts = is_array($postMeta) ? array_filter($postMeta) : [$postMeta];
```

This will make sure that if get_post_meta returns a singular result instead of an array, it will create an array with it in, otherwise it will do the `array_filter()` you wanted

Comment: You're missing the second argument to `array_filter()`. And you're not filtering the result if it's singular.

Comment: @Barmar why would you filter a single result and OP's snippet doesn't contain a second parameter for his array_filter, this is because it is optional, please read the PHP documentation for the function

Comment: I misread the last parameter to `get_post_meta` as being for `array_filter`.

Comment: Thanks for the info guys. It's a bit over my head. Sorry to waste your time.